# Displaying contact name upon SMS or IP voice call, after (Android) phone has been rebooted

Tags: android, sms, android-contacts, rich-communications-services

We are developing an SMS and RCS (Rich Commmunications Services) app.

The phone can be in two modes (after reboot):

```
- Direct Boot (for 7.0)
- and for non Direct Boot mode (pre 7.0)
```

Two possible events:

```
1. Upon receiving a message (SMS or RCS)
2. Upon a RCS IP voice call
```

Questions:

Where are contacts data [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html] stored? (in Credential encrypted storage or Device encrypted storage?)

How does the app display the contact name (first/last name) upon receiving a message or getting a voice call?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure i'm following. why not use the standard ContactsContract APIs to get the name? all you need is to lookup a contact name by phone-number?

Comment: is it possible when the phone is in Direct Boot

Comment: have you tried to simply query for it, and to see if it works? if it doesn't work, what's the error/stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: There are too many OS versions and hardware models, so it is really impractical to try first because if it works on one it may not work on other. I'd appreciate if someone could provide an authoritative answer.